# Adding elements in an array every 12 items

Tags: javascript

How would you best turn `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]` into `[12,12]`

Basically reducing an array into an aggregate every 12 items.

This is my not so elegant attempt:

```
let arr = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
let result = 0;
let finalArr = [];

arr.forEach((item,index) => {
   result += item;
   if((index+1) % 12 === 0) {
       finalArr.push(result)
       result = 0
   }
})
```

Can this be done a bit more elegantly? Perhaps using `reduce()`? I haven't used js in a while so I am a bit rusty! Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks pretty good already. You could change the `forEach` to `reduce` to turn the `finalArr`'s `let` into a `const`, but that's not so important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function reduceGroupByN(arr, count, fn) {
  const out = []

  if (count <= 1) throw new Error("Grouping must be greater than 1")

  for (var last = 0; last < arr.length; last += count) {
    out.push(arr.slice(last, last + count).reduce(fn))
  }

  return out
}

const arr = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

const result = reduceGroupByN(arr, 12, (a, b) => a + b)
```

Comment: Nice and clean.

Answer (score 1):

For a more general solution, consider using a function that chunks an array into slices. (This sort of utility function is relatively common already.) Then call that function and add up the resulting subarrays with `.map`:

```js
const arr = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];

const chunk = (arr, length) => arr.reduce((a, num, i) => {
  const chunkIndex = Math.floor(i / length);
  if (!a[chunkIndex]) {
    a[chunkIndex] = [];
  }
  a[chunkIndex].push(num);
  return a;
}, []);

const finalArr = chunk(arr, 12)
  .map(
    subarr => subarr.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
  );
console.log(finalArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of angering the modern JS gods, there is still something to be said for the performance and simplicity of a classic solution.

On my machine this runs two to three times faster compared to the other answers.

```js
let arr =[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
let finalArr=[]
let chunkSize=12
for (n=0; n < arr.length;)
{
  for( result=0, m=0; m < chunkSize; m++, n++)
  {
     result+=arr[n]
  }
  finalArr.push(result)
}

console.log(finalArr)
```